# Formally Correct way to update public "Constants" in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a constants class in my C# project. I am using a `Constants` class, which holds values which I am using to configure a OAuth Login Call. Whether someone clicks "Login with Google" or "Login with Facebook" etc. defines what value these public constants should be.

I am a self taught programmer, so can see that I might be likely to do something here which can cause issues. So how are you supposed to handle this.

Here is what I have at the moment, but I would like to have just `APP_ID`, which would have a value dependant on which login button was pressed.

I could set these in a sub routine, but I am not sure if that is best practice?

```
public class Constants
{

    public const string FB_APP_ID = "xxxxxx";
    public const string FB_SCOPE = "";
    public const string FB_APP_NAME = "xxxx";
    public const string AUTH_URI = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/";
    public const string RETURN_URI = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

    public const string G_APP_ID = "yyyyyyy.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    public const string S_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";

}
```

## Update:

Just to note a few points about my set up. I am developing using Xamarin for cross platform mobile development, this isn't very relevant. However, it does mean that my solution has 3 projects, a Portable Class Library, an iOS project and an Android one. So I have some buttons described on a view page in my PCL, with some `Button.Clicked` handlers behind them. This is where I would like to set the value of my global OAuth details class. I then have to reference this OAuth instance from my iOS and Android projects, whether it is a Google, Facebook or other set of values.

Comment: You should create classes that deals with the different login/authorization providers, these would have their own way of being configured but your main application should ideally know only which of these providers it should use.

Comment: Why are you interested in `APP_ID`? What is your calling code going to do with it? Why should it care at all? Why are these constants? What are you trying to accomplish? Can't you just introduce an abstract `AuthenticationProvider` class on which you call `Authenticate()`, and whether the concrete type (`FacebookAuthProvider`, `GoogleAuthProvider`) uses tokens, apps, scopes, URIs or pigeons to do the authentication is not interesting at all to your code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have some code which actually carries out the login process with the user, I am trying to avoid writing this for each button, as it is exactly the same, except from the values. So I want some references in that code, which I can work behind to configure base don which login provider has been selected.

Comment: The quick solution is to use a static property you set with the information you need to update.  The long term solution is to get some basic books, such as CLR Via C# and read them thoroughly.  You'll never regret taking the long term solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to create classes, at least to hold the data, possibly even to do some custom work for the specific provider.

Something like this:

```
public class OAuthInfo
{
    public string AppId {get;set;}
    public string Scope {get;set;}
    public string AppName  {get;set;}
    public string AuthUri {get;set;}
    public string ReturnUri  {get;set;}
}
```

And instantiate an instance:

```
var facebookData = new OAuthInfo()
                   {
                       AppId = "xxxxxx",
                       Scope = "",
                       AppName  = "xxxx",
                       AuthUri = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/",
                       ReturnUri  = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"
                   };
```

You can pass that along where you need it.

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks as though this is the answer, but how would I use this. I currently have three files in use, my `Constants` class, or what ever you wish to call it. My button click handler, where I want to configure my values, one for FB and one for Google, in your example, this is where I would put `new OAuthinfo()`. The finally, the code which manages the Login, this is split between an iOS project and an Android project. How do I reference the active `OAuthInfo` object from here?

Comment: You have to set it somewhere, maybe in some manager class. Can you store it somewhere on the start of your application?

Comment: Well, I only know when the user has pressed a button on the login screen. So I have several click handlers which is where I am currently setting up these class objects. However, if I do it there, I don't know how to reference this data from the last file.

Comment: I have added an update to the question to outline this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `app.config` file to hold these so called constants. The config fill will be brought over with the application and read during run-time. That way the config can be changed by the user(?) if needed without re-compiling the program.

See

- [How to: Add an Application Configuration File to a C# Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx)
- [Managing Application Settings (.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx)

  ---

Then you can add an `appSettings` node to the `app.config` file to hold all the application values, here is one:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
    <appSettings>
       <add key="TargetURL" value="https://Omegacoder.Com" />
    </appSettings>
 </configuration/>
```

And extract as such (if using C# 6 found in Visual Studio 2015, otherwise *set the property in code by call `ConfigurationManager` and assigning it that way*):

```
 public static string TargetUrl { get; set; } = 
                               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TargetURL"];
```

Note I put my *constants* into statics, but one can simply call `ConfigurationManger` at anytime in your program and does not have to *assign* the value as shown in my example.

---

**Update**

At this time the Xamarin projects do not support application configuration files.

Comment: 1+ for the term "so-called" constants

Comment: app.config files don't apply for Xamarin projects

Comment: @Jason Good spot! lol... here is a very relevent forum post about the lack of app.config in xamarin... https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5827/app-config

Answer (score 1):

Following on from my comment about configuration...

In a typical Windows/Web .NET application you would use the `ConfigurationManager` classes with custom configuration sections to do the gruntwork of the OAuth provider configuration work for you.

These classes are "missing" in Xamarin apparently and there is an extended discussion about best practice in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5827/app-config) on the Xamarin forums.

This thread can be summarised as:

- Use a static class with static properties with #if compiler directives for the different environment deployments if you have environmental config changes.
- Roll your own XML config file which you can read and write to easily using standard .NET XML handling (like Linq to XML).

IMHO the XML config file would be my preference with a reader class that is a Singleton implementation, much like the `ConfigurationManager` is. Why? Because XML config files are an established pattern in .NET and anyone reading your code will understand how/why you're working with the class that way...

If you put your Singleton in a commonly accessible assembly and make sure that it loads the config on construction, it should be available in multiple places without needing to worry about duplicating the code or reinstantiating after the first construction for the lifetime of the application and if you need it, you simply add a dependency to that assembly and use the instance.